# Powershell script to search folders using .csv files without Path

Tags: powershell

I am new to the powershell scripting and hence need one help in scripting, the script which I am looking for should search for the folders as per the entries in `.csv` file, please note that it should search for the folders in the drive without knowing the path and move it to the destination.

I did some research and created below script which is taking data from `.txt` file and moving the data to the destination however it does not work if I just write `C:\` at the place of source folder.

Request you to please help me :)

```
Get-Content C:\abc.txt | 
   Foreach-Object { 
                    move-item -path "C:\0123\$_" -destination "C:\To Archive\$_"
                  }
```

Comment: What does the content of abc.txt look like? A singular column with items to be moved? I'd assume that Get-Content with a text file will return a string.

Comment: Can you give an example input (source file system) and an example output (destination file system)? It's a little unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Guys first of all I wanted to thank you for answering my query, I will just let you know what exactly I am looking for. I have a .csv file in which i have one column with name called project in which I have projects.
e.g:
Projects
1234AA5678
0987II6543

Now I want to design a script which should read this .CSV file and search for these folders on all the drives located on my computer and move it to the destination which could be C:\test

Answer (score 0):

With what you've given, I'd do something like the following:

```
$File = Import-Csv C:\share\test\files.txt 

Foreach($fileName in $File.FileName)
{
    Move-Item -path "C:\share\test\OldLocation\$fileName" -Destination "C:\share\test\NewLocation\$fileName"
}
```

I did this with a .csv file that had one column whose title was FileName. Notable differences from your code include using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet and specifying the .csv header title in the foreach loop.

---

If you wanted to do this with a single command:

```
Import-Csv C:\share\test\files.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item -path "C:\share\test\OldLocation\$($_.[csvHeader])" -Destination "C:\share\test\NewLocation\$($_.[csvHeader])"
}
```

Where csvHeader is the title of the column in your .csv file.

---

My .csv file looked like:

```
FileName
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```